# Supersymmetry beyond $D=11$ spacetime dimensions

Tags: string-theory, quantum-spin, supersymmetry, spacetime-dimensions, higher-spin

Taking into account the higher spin theories, from which string theory is an effective field theory, I just wondering if there is something to do to extend supersymmetry to any dimension without any mathematical consistency failure. Could  string-theory/M-theory be formulated in such a way fields of ANY spin naturally occur? After all, we have F-theory or S-theory in 12D and 13D.

Comment: The Nahm classification, c.f. http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/week158.html , implies by elementary arguments $D = 11$ is the maximum dimension

Comment: Some people do consider theories with more supersymmetries, e.g., Toppan in his papers...

Comment: Sure but then, from that link, you have to drop "the reasonable assumption that there be no massless particles with spins greater than two" and this is not a good idea apparently because "there's a paper by Witten in the above book that contains references to papers that supposedly explain why particles of spin > 2 are bad" :p

Comment: To be fair, there is study of higher spin theories, so "spin > 2 are bad" is not taken as seriously as it used to be.

Comment: Related to [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/169695/)

Answer (score 1):

The papers https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.2476 and https://arxiv.org/abs/1504.00602 by Choi discuss supergravity in twelve dimensions.

Comment: Note that Choi considers one dimension compactified from the start, cf. the abstract: "This condition prevents us from violating the condition on the maximal number of real supercharges, which should be thirty-two." In other words, the amount of SUSY is just as in eleven dimensions.